# Javascript OOP – strange constructor

Tags: javascript, oop, constructor, singleton

Today I've found an exercise which I cannot solve... Google does not help. 
Could you give me a prompt where to find a solution?

```
a = new Pepper, b = new Pepper;
```

How to make it in a way:

```
a === b
true
```

What is the difference between new Pepper and new Pepper()? I do not get it...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all there is no difference between `new Pepper()` and `new Pepper` apart from the fact that the last one will hurt your feelings. Thanks to Douglas Crockford if you know what I mean.

How to make `a === b`? *Singleton* is the answer. Check this out:

```
function Pepper () {
 if (Pepper.instance) {
  return Pepper.instance
 }
 Pepper.instance = this;
}
a = new Pepper, b = new Pepper;
a === b
```

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lends/j2p96rdd/)

If you want to know more about Singletons, read this: [Learning JavaScript Design Patterns](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#singletonpatternjavascript)

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! BTW, What do you mean "hurt your feelings"?
Who's Douglas Crockford?

Comment: @Vyap [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) is a tool which was made by _Douglas Crockford_ for hurting feelings. Just write down your code there and you will see. _Douglas Crockford_ was the first to specify and popularize the JSON format, also he has written a really nice book _JavaScript: The Good Parts_ and there are lots of his lectures on youtube.

Answer (score 2):

It’s not possible to make two different objects compare as equal with `===`. There is no difference between `new Pepper` and `new Pepper()`, but when you call the constructor twice, it will construct two objects. Note that `{} === {}` is also `false`.